# access to controller object via service

Tags: angularjs, post, angular-ngmodel, angular-services, angular-components

This is my controller :

```
constructor(Auth, $http, $rootScope, $log, $scope, $uibModal, loginTemplate, demandCity, signupTemplate, socket) {
  this.isLoggedIn = Auth.isLoggedIn;
  this.$http = $http;
  this.socket = socket;
  this.awesomeDemands = [];

  $scope.newDemand = demandCity.newDemand;

    $scope.addDemand=function(){
        demandCity.addDemand()
        console.log($scope.newDemand);
    };
}
```

This is my service :

```
angular.module('merciPublicApp')
  .service('demandCity',['$http', 'socket', function ($http, socket) {

      this.$http = $http;
      this.socket = socket;
      this.awesomeDemands = [];

    this.addDemand = function() {
      if (this.newDemand) {
      console.log("addDemand");
        this.$http.post('/api/demands', {
          id: 30,
          city_id: this.newDemand,
          artist_id: 1,
          user_id: 1
        });
        this.newDemand = '';
        }
    }

    this.deleteDemand = function(demand) {
      this.$http.delete('/api/demands/' + demand._id);
    }
  }]);
```

This is my HTML :

```
<div class="postNewCityTemplate">
    <div class="hidden-xs">
        <div class="cardCity">
            <div class="cardCity-City">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Add a new demand here." ng-model="newDemand">
                <button ng-click="addDemand()">Add Demand</button>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>Ajouter blablabla à la liste</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="visible-xs">
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to get the content of $scope.newDemand from my controller to my service. The addDemand() function is not working because this.newDemand is empty, I basically need to replace this.newDemand but I don't know how...

Thanks in advance for helping me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass data to function  demandCity.addDemand().

In Controller:

```
demandCity.addDemand($scope.newDemand);
```

then in service :

```
 this.addDemand = function(passedNewDemand) {
      if (passedNewDemand) {
      console.log("addDemand");
        this.$http.post('/api/demands', {
          id: 30,
          city_id: this.newDemand,
          artist_id: 1,
          user_id: 1
        });
        this.newDemand = '';
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes don't worry i know, but they are telling me to wait before I can accept :)